# ioct multiple arguments passing

Tags: c, kernel-module, ioctl

I try to pass two arguments from user space program to change a buffer size and number of buffer on char device. I tried multiple cast I get always cast errors

```
 error: cannot convert to a pointer type copy_from_user((char *)msg, arg, sizeof(msg));
```

or

```
cannot convert to a pointer typecopy_from_user((char *)msg, (char *)arg, sizeof(msg));
```

header.h

```
struct ioctl_arguments {
         int block_number;
         int block_size;
 };
```

the kernel module and the c program include both the header.h

c program

```
#define DEVICE_PATH "/dev/driver"
#define MAGIC_NO 'k'
struct ioctl_arguments args;
#define IOCTL_CMD _IOWR(MAGIC_NO, 0, args)
int main()
{
    int fd;
    args.block_number = 10;
    args.block_size = 10;
    fd = open(DEVICE_PATH, O_RDWR);
    ioctl(fd, IOCTL_CMD,&args);
    close(fd);
    return 0;
}
```

device driver

```
static int BlockNumber = 20;
static int BlockSize = 5;
struct ioctl_arguments msg;

static int sample_ioctl (struct file *filp, unsigned int cmd, unsigned long arg);

static int sample_ioctl (struct file *filp, unsigned int cmd, unsigned long arg) 
{

  // copy two parameters from outside, we use struct
  copy_from_user((char *)msg, (char *)arg, sizeof(msg));
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [char device catch multiple (int) ioctl-arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8849445/char-device-catch-multiple-int-ioctl-arguments)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your device-driver function `arg` is in reality a pointer so that cast is valid, but `msg` is not a pointer so the cast to pointer is not valid. You should use `&msg` (just like you use `&args` in the user-space code).

Answer (score 0):

you can have your struct for example:
In your usersapce:

```c
struct mesg
{
  unsigned long addr;
  unsigned long len;
};

struct mesg msg;
msg.addr = 94668954824704;
msg.len = 4;

ret = fd_ioctl, IOCTL_BASE_GET_MUIR, &msg);
```

In your kernel driver:

```c
struct mesg *msg = kmalloc(sizeof(struct mesg), GFP_DMA);
if (copy_from_user(msg, (void *)arg, sizeof(struct mesg))){
    return -EFAULT;
}
printk("Debug %lu %lu\n", msg->addr, msg->len);
```